# How to get the time difference with minutes and seconds?

Tags: r, time

I have two columns of time information using minutes and seconds in a data.frame without additional date information, now I want to calculate the difference between these two columns and get a new column for *diff_time* (end_time-start_time) in either seconds (**diff_time1**) or in minutes and seconds as expressed in the original variables(**diff_time2**), how can I calculate this in R?
For example:

```
      start_time  end_time  diff_time1  diff_time2
       12'10"     16'23"      4'13"      253
       1'05"      76'20"      75'15"     4515  
       96'10"     120'22"     24'12"     1452
```

Comment: Are `start_time` and `end_time` currently stored as strings?

Comment: yes, it's string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that your times are stored as strings, in which case the quote denoting seconds must be escaped:

```
times <- data.frame(start_time = c("12'10\"", "1'05\"", "96'10\""),
                    end_time   = c("16'23\"", "76'20\"", "120'22\"")
                   )
```

Then you can use `lubridate::ms` to convert to minutes + seconds and do the calculations. You'll need to do some additional text conversions if you want the results for `diff_time1` as strings:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

times %>% 
  mutate(diff_time1 = ms(end_time) - ms(start_time)) %>%
  mutate(diff_time2 = as.numeric(diff_time1)) %>%
  mutate(diff_time1 = gsub("M ", "'", diff_time1)) %>% 
  mutate(diff_time1 = gsub("S", "\"", diff_time1))

  start_time end_time diff_time1 diff_time2
1     12'10"   16'23"      4'13"        253
2      1'05"   76'20"     75'15"       4515
3     96'10"  120'22"     24'12"       1452
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store separate the minutes and seconds and store them as `difftime` objects, which can be added and subtracted:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(start_time = c("12'10\"", "1'05\"", "96'10\""), 
    end_time = c("16'23\"", "76'20\"", "120'22\"")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), .Names = c("start_time", "end_time"))

df %>% 
    separate(start_time, c('start_min', 'start_sec'), convert = TRUE, extra = 'drop') %>% 
    separate(end_time, c('end_min', 'end_sec'), convert = TRUE, extra = 'drop') %>%
    mutate(start = as.difftime(start_min, units = 'mins') + as.difftime(start_sec, units = 'secs'), 
           end = as.difftime(end_min, units = 'mins') + as.difftime(end_sec, units = 'secs'),
           diff_time = end - start)

#>   start_min start_sec end_min end_sec     start       end diff_time
#> 1        12        10      16      23  730 secs  983 secs  253 secs
#> 2         1         5      76      20   65 secs 4580 secs 4515 secs
#> 3        96        10     120      22 5770 secs 7222 secs 1452 secs
```